# MVVM design pattern problems

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and MVVM and am struggling a lot with how to design my app (hence lots of questions on here) and am about to do a refactor. I've got a SQL backend and am using LINQtoSQL so the classes that LINQTOSQL generates will be my model. I have yet to see a good comprehensive example of how to keep the model classes away from the view - in the example I'm looking at now a view is binding to ModelClass.Something instead of having a ViewModel property which references ModelClass.Something. Am I correct in thinking this is bad (if that field changes in the db the View breaks)?

What I'm struggling with at the moment is dropdown lists. Example: I have a lookup table called MessageType with an id and text field and a repository method to fetch them. So in my view I want to avoid binding the DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValue path to fields on my Model's MessageType class so do I need to make a new class and expose that class's properties in my ViewModel? Like this:

```
public class MessageTypeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MessageTypeViewModel(MessageType t)
    {
        MessageTypeText = t.messageTypeText;
        MessageTypeId = t.messageTypeId;
    }
    public string MessageTypeText { get; private set; }//bind DisplayMember and SelectedValue to these properties
    public int MessageTypeId { get; private set; }
}
```

populating like this:

```
get
{
if (textMessageSelectionOptions == null)
    {
        var list = repository.GetMessageTypes().Select(x=>new MessageTypeViewModel(x)).ToList();
        textMessageSelectionOptions =new ReadOnlyCollection<MessageTypeViewModel>(list);
    }
return textMessageSelectionOptions;
}
```

Also I have a Mission object that has a foreign key to MessageType so how do I bind the combo box's SelectedItem to mission.MessageType given that I now have this new class? I'm really struggling to get the pattern with the mission object, its children and its parents and I can't find any comprehensive examples where people are doing CRUD operations with MVVM. Am I going over the top or missing something?

Comment: Unless your view model actually adds behaviour to the class (e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation or a view-specific command/property) then I wouldn't wrap it in a view model - it just results in unnecessary maintenance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of MVVM is to make your application more maintainable, and save you from having to spend lots of time debugging tightly-coupled spaghetti code. If a pure implementation of the MVVM pattern achieves this for you, then it is worth your while to apply it fully. On the other hand, if you spend a whole lot of time writing ViewModel proxies for your model classes, but your application is small and won't be changed much once it's finished, a purist approach to MVVM might be overkill.

If you want to avoid exposing the model to the view entirely, you're probably going to have to create a ViewModel-specific version of your model and replicate all of the dependencies (e.g. Mission -> MessageType) while you're at it.

You might find this article useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff798279.aspx, especially the section on collections.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looks useful although I don't understand it all yet. I think I'm going to be pragmatic and forget about writing proxy classes for my dropdown data as it seems a bit over the top to make an extra class for each one given that they are unlikely to change.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `MessageType` is really an immutable value type, so I don't think the view-model is necessary.

Assuming you are working with a view that is bound to something like a `MissionViewModel` and there is a dropdown you want to populate with `MessageType` options bound to the property for which you've shown the getter, I think what you are doing is fine.

Populating the drop-down list with `MessageType` objects (by binding to `ItemsSource`) should by default display the result of calling `ToString()` on each item. If that does not give you the results you desire, you could go with the view-model or maybe create an `IValueConverter` implementation to display what you want.

If you have view-models in your drop-down instead of the `MessageType` objects themselves, then you can bind `mission.MessageType` to `SelectedItem` by using an `IValueConverter` to convert the view-model to `MessageType`. To perform this conversion, you can

A. expose the underlying `MessageType` as a public property of the view-model,
 B. make the view-model itself implement `IValueConverter` so the conversion operation can access the private `MessageType` field, or
 C. create the `IValueConverter` as a nested class of the view-model, again so it can access the private `MessageType` field

One downside to option B is that you'll need a public parameterless constructor to add the converter in a XAML `ResourceDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

You neeed to employ commanding instead of directly accessing from view from viewmodel or vice versa. Refer to [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)